# word used as a noun and equivalent of an adverb in sentence

Tags: grammar-identification

My book has given the following two rules and its examples about word used as a noun and adverb in a sentence. Though I am having hard time to understand the difference between the meaning when it is used as a noun and equivalent of an adverb in the given sentence.

Adjectives of nationality are written with a capital letter when used as a noun to refer to the language or the school subject.

- > Sie spricht, kann, lernt, liest (kein, gut) **Deutsch**, Russisch, Englisch.

They have a small letter when used as the equivalent of an adverb:

- > Redet sie jetzt **deutsch** oder niederländisch?

Answer (score 4):

What you call "Adjectives of nationality" are languages. This is something different. There are many people who speak **English**<sub>*(a language)*</sub> but the most of them are not **English**<sub>*(a nationality)*</sub>. You are talking about languages, not about nationalities. There are also languages with no matching nationality (*Latin*) and vice versa (*Mexican*).

Languages have names, and names are always nouns and so, when you use those names of languages in German, you always have to write them with an uppercase first letter:

> Sie lernt **Deutsch.**

Here the word *Deutsch* is telling you *what* she is learning. It does not tell you *how* she is learning. So here we use the name of the language, and this is a noun. This is true in German and in English (and I think in most other languages too).

In German this is an accusative object, and you can replace it with another accusative object (objects always contain a noun or a pronoun):

> Sie lernt **eine Sprache.**

Here you again can ask *"What is she learning?"* and will get the answer *"eine Sprache" (a language).* But now you can see it even more clear that *Sprache* is a noun, because it is used with an article (only nouns can have articles).

Normally you don't use languages with an article, but if you add an attribute, you even can do this trick:

> Sie lernt ***ein*** veraltetes Deutsch. (She learns an outdated German.)

Here *"ein veraltetes Deutsch"* is the accusative object.

---

The other example:

> Redet sie jetzt **deutsch**?

Here the word *deutsch* tells you *how* she is speaking. She could speak *loud* or *quick* or *german*.

But when we talk about a language, and when the verb is *speak, talk, mumble, chat, shout* or similar, you also can argue, that you want to tell *what* she is speaking, talking etc. And then you can argue that it again is a noun:

> Redet sie jetzt **Deutsch?**

Which is correct too, but less common. So here both versions are correct.

---

But in this example is it alwas must be in lower case:

> Dieses Buch ist **deutsch.** *(This book is german.)*

There is no way to interpret *deutsch* as a noun here. I very clearly is an adjective here (is is a part of the predicate), and therefore has to be written in lower case.

Also always in lower case:

> - Das ist ein **deutsches** Buch.  (adjective, used as an attribute of a noun)
> - Sie trägt ihr Referat **deutsch** vor.  (adjective, used as adverbial)

But:

> - Sie trägt ihr Referat **auf Deutsch** vor.

Here *"auf Deutsch"* is an adverbial which consists of a preposition and a noun, and becasue it is anoun it has to be written with an upper case first letter.